# Calculate percentage on DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of each crime of the following Dataframe:

```
        Violent     Murder      Larceny_Theft   Vehicle_Theft
Year
1960    288460      3095700     1855400         328200
1961    289390      3198600     1913000         336000
1962    301510      3450700     2089600         366800
1963    316970      3792500     2297800         408300
1964    364220      4200400     2514400         472800
```

So I should calculate first the total of crimes per year and then use that to calculate the percentage of each crime. I was trying the following:

```
> perc = (crime *100) / crime.sum(axis=1)
```

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use function [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) for divide by `Series`:

```
perc = crime.mul(100).div(crime.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
#perc = (crime *100).div(crime.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (perc)
       Violent     Murder  Larceny_Theft  Vehicle_Theft
Year                                                   
1960  5.180899  55.600457      33.323994       5.894651
1961  5.044283  55.753976      33.345012       5.856730
1962  4.856320  55.579268      33.656487       5.907925
1963  4.650675  55.644649      33.713981       5.990695
1964  4.822943  55.621029      33.295285       6.260742
```