# Using percentage and grouping with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rest_Id': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10],
'Desert': [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'Kids Menu': [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
'Shakes' : [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
'Critic' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
'ratings_sum': [451,1302,64,356,43,230,153,589,83,201,18,75,292,1197,243,632,326,839,74,267]})
df
```

How can I plot charts using seaborn/pyplot or others that shows across each Food type i.e. Burgers, Salads etc. the critics "%preferances" ?

If Critic A prefers "Kids Menu" more than B, irrespective of the "Rest_id" using simple percentages
For example if out of total of 3000 ratings by A  if 1500 are for "Kids menu" we will assume A prefers "Kids menu" 50%

I looked at this [Calculate percentage on DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831217/calculate-percentage-on-dataframe)

I can't figure out how to get the right dataframe for the charting. I was thinking of using pairplot with "Critic" as hue. 
What's throwing me is using .div and the transpose for the right data frame for the charts.

Comment: Can you show your expected output DataFrame?

Comment: I don't have a figure yet. But I am looking for a chart for each "Food Type" with a bar for Critic A and a bar for col B